# Friction or not?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential, friction, conservative-field

Say I have a differential equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  Newtons Equation :

\begin{align}
    \frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}=&\dot{\gamma}(t),
    \nonumber
    \\
    \frac{d\dot{\gamma}(t)}{dt}=&-\nabla V(\gamma(t)),
\end{align}

where $V:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$. Does one interpret the $V$ term as a friction term? or an external potential like gravity? I don't know any physics please be kind!

Answer (score 0):

Friction is a non conservative force. A conservative force can be written as the negative gradient of some potential, namely $$\vec F_{\rm conservative} = -\nabla U$$

Since friction is non-conservative, therefore it cannot be described as a gradient of some potential.

Gravity on the other hand is a conservative force. So $V$ can indeed be a gravitational potential.

Comment: Can you add a frictional term into the equation I wrote ?