# Conservative vs Dissipative Forces

Tags: forces, energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, dissipation

I will be speaking very loosely since I am not a physicist.

Say a system evolves via a dissipative force, then usually as time moves on some energy functional will be decreasing.

If a system has both dissipative forces and conservative forces then isn't the "net force" still dissipative its like saying $-$something$+0=-$something? Hence wont this dissipative conservative  system also minimise some energy functional?

Comment: Well, yeah, that's what pretty much every real system on earth does. Conservative (gravity) + Dissipative (friction) in total gives you a dissipative system.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607422/2451